# ASP Classic: recordset recordcount -1 for new table but older ones ok?

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

I'm working with Classic ASP accessing an Access database on our webserver.  The application checks for sensor updates to the web/table, ie printing the last 5 records.  This code has worked for several tables historically.  I recently added a new table to the database and when I modify the code to retrieve records from the new table I get a recordcount = -1 and it only outputs the last record.  I have read about the Recordset Cursor but not sure I understand how to apply that to my code and also why the code does not work for this new table?  Here is the basic code to retrieve the records for printing:

```
WebName = "OurWeb"
MySite = "filedsn=" & Server.MapPath("/" & WebName & "/files/reffiles/accessdsn.dsn") & ";DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("/" & WebName & "/files/reffiles/loger.mdb") & ";DefaultDir=" _
& Server.MapPath("/" & WebName & "/") & ";"

set MyDatabase = server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
if err.number <> 0 then response.write("<p>ODBC Error</p>")
Mydatabase.open MySite 

set LastMyDate = MyDatabase.Execute("SELECT Format(Max([Date_Time]),'mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss') AS Expr1 FROM Charger2;")

set LastMYDate = MyDatabase.Execute("SELECT Charger2.id FROM Charger2 WHERE Charger2.date_Time = #" & lastMGdate.fields(0).value & "#;")

MyIDLast = LastMyDate.fields(0).value -5
set LastMyRecord = MyDatabase.Execute("SELECT Charger2.id,  Charger2.date_time,  Charger2.INV_vdc,  Charger2.INV_adc FROM Charger2 WHERE (((Charger2.id) > (" & MyIDLast & ")));")
```

Id is an Autonumber Integer. At this point the recordcount property is "-1". When I run that Select query directly from the Access Program interface it returns the right number.

Thanks for any help and insight into why this issue is happening with this table...RDK

Answer (score 2):

The recordcount returns -1 if the recordset isn't fully loaded.

When using an aggregate query that returns a single record, it's often fully loaded. But if you filter a nonindexed column, it might not be.

If you want to reliably use `.RecordCount`, use `.MoveLast` first to fully load the recordset.

Comment: I added "lastmyrecord.movelast" after the "Set Lastmyrecord…" statement and now I get this error "Rowset does not support fetching backward"

Comment: @RDK you need to make sure you fetch a recordset that actually supports moving forwards and backwards, either by changing the connection properties (client-side cursor), using `Recordset.Open` instead of `Connection.Execute` or an ADODB command object. `Connection.Execute` is generally used when no return value is needed and offers very little control over what's returned

Comment: Isn't [Select Count(*) From Query](http://www.slxdeveloper.com/page.aspx?action=viewarticle&articleid=33) the the recommended recordcount strategy

Comment: @ComputerVersteher If you only want a count then yes. If you want to do further things with a recordset (such as display all records, or the count + the first X if the count is larger than Y) then no. Reading the question, I think OP wants to do more with the recordset than just determine the count.

Comment: OK, I'll work on modifying the code, BUT the real question is, why am I   seeing  this issue with this new table?  Is that something I may have done during the setup?

Comment: It's probably just related to the way you're using the table. Often, it's a good thing, because you load the table in a way that allows you to work with the recordset without fully loading it first, which makes operations that don't require the entire recordset much faster. But since you're using .Execute, it's hard to tell exactly what's happening under the hood.

Comment: OK, I tried to convert my code to use the "more approprite" rs.open …. form but managed only to generate lots of errors.  Then, in frustration, I trashed to old page/code and stated coding using my old method from a blank page.  Now it works correctly!  Evidently I had a VERY subtile coding error in my page which I was not able to see.  Anyway, problem addressed and the issue was "Probable User Error, check your code".  Thanks for your time and suggestions....